# Largest collection of square matrices with zero on diagonal of products

Tags: matrices, manifolds, tensors

Let $n$ be a positive integer. What is the largest integer $k$ for which there exist $n\times n$ matrices $M_1,M_2,\ldots,M_k$ and $N_1,N_2,\ldots,N_k$ such that for all $i$ and $j$, the matrix product $M_iN_j$ has a zero entry somewhere on its diagonal if and only if $i\neq j$.

Comment: Can you provide some context ? Also, what are your thoughts ?

Comment: I ask the same question as Ewan Delanoy ; what are your thoughts ? **Please, answer us**. Having a zero on the diagonal can be interpreted as a zero dot product, thus an orthogonality between at least a certain line of $M_i$ with a certain column of $N_j$

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the comment. I think your observation is highly relevant to the problem. The integer $n$ is the dimension of the space, either a differentiable manifold or its tangent space at some point. The matrices should be related to coordinate representations of linear transformations, or perhaps components of tensors. I apologize that I don't know much more about the context either, but the question is related to geometry and manifolds.